# Paypal post problem

Tags: asp.net, forms, post

document.aspnetForm.action = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

I use master page and paypal payment page but giving error "document.aspnetform is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your question whether you are doing this on the client using JavaScript or on the server in C#. I guess the former as you are using `document` all lower case. Either way check your capitalisation - Javascript *is* case sensitive so you may need `document.AspNetForm` or something similar as your identifier. Just make sure it matches up to whatever the title of the form is in the source code.

Comment: same code running my local and other web site but other server add ContenPlaceHolder1_ my local and runnig server add ct100_ why is the difference